# python subprocess.call terminates without notice

Tags: python

i have a script in python that call subprocess to encode video file below

```
        args1 = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "my niece.mkv"]
        args2 = MyConfig.DefaultFFMPEGParam + " " + crf + " " + output + ""
        args = args2.split(' ')
        args1.extend(args)

        print "EncodeReal : " + uniqueno + " : Try Encode"
        print " ".join(args1)
        subprocess.call(" ".join(args1), shell=True)
```

the print statement successfully prints out below commands

```
ffmpeg -i "/home/Downloads/my niece.mkv" -tune animation -keyint_min 12 -sc_threshold 45 -bf 8 -b_strategy 2 -refs 10 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -direct-pred auto -me_range 24 -me_method umh -subq 9 -trellis 2 -vcodec libx264 -crf 28.0 /home/Downloads/output.mkv
```

which if running this command in script it works well, however if it runs by subprocess.call, it encounter

```
ffmpeg version git-2013-12-30-61d43a2 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Dec 30 2013 11:02:28 with gcc 4.4.7 (GCC) 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)
  configuration: --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/root/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/root/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/root/bin --extra-libs=-ldl --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk_aac --enable-libx264
  libavutil      52. 59.100 / 52. 59.100
  libavcodec     55. 47.100 / 55. 47.100
  libavformat    55. 22.101 / 55. 22.101
  libavdevice    55.  5.102 / 55.  5.102
  libavfilter     4.  0.103 /  4.  0.103
  libswscale      2.  5.101 /  2.  5.101
  libswresample   0. 17.104 /  0. 17.104
  libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100


[1]+  Stopped                 python MonitorService.py
```

It stops by itself! any reason?

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the command to see if it still happens? For example, does a simple ffmpeg call to convert a .wav file to .mp3 still have the same problem? You've got a *lot* of parameters in there so it's hard to tell what might be causing your problem.

Comment: I have some doubts regarding your output. Why is the filename quoted in the final command-line if your code does *not* take that into account? Anyway you should provide a *minimal working example* aka [sscce](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I completely agree with @RogueThinking. Your problem is the space in `"my niece.mkv"`. Another way around the problem is to use `subprocess.call` with an iterable list of arguments rather than the full string concatenated. The arguments will then be passed properly without worrying about quote escaping.

From the [documentation for subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) (emphasis added):

> args is required for all calls and should be a string, or a sequence
>   of program arguments. **Providing a sequence of arguments is generally
>   preferred, as it allows the module to take care of any required
>   escaping and quoting of arguments (e.g. to permit spaces in file
>   names)**. If passing a single string, either shell must be True (see
>   below) or else the string must simply name the program to be executed
>   without specifying any arguments.

For example, a full working version using lists looks like this:

```
import subprocess

def run():
    DefaultFFMPEGParam = "-tune animation -keyint_min 12 -sc_threshold 45 -bf 8 -b_strategy 2 -refs 10 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qcomp 0.6 -direct-pred auto -me_range 24 -me_method umh -subq 9 -trellis 2 -vcodec libx264" \
        .split(' ')
    crf = ['-crf', '28.0']
    output = "output2.mkv"

    # list concatenation
    args1 = ["ffmpeg", "-i", "my niece.mkv"] + DefaultFFMPEGParam + crf + [output,]

    print args1
    # prints:
    #
    # ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'my niece.mkv', '-tune', 'animation', '-keyint_min', '12',
    #  '-sc_threshold', '45', '-bf', '8', '-b_strategy', '2', '-refs', '10', '-qmin',
    #  '10', '-qmax', '51', '-qcomp', '0.6', '-direct-pred', 'auto', '-me_range', '24',
    #  '-me_method', 'umh', '-subq', '9', '-trellis', '2', '-vcodec', 'libx264',
    #  '-crf', '28.0',
    #  'output2.mkv']    

    subprocess.call(args1)

run()
```

Note in this case I was able to omit `shell=True` and the call still executes properly.

Answer (score 1):

The print string you provide cannot be generated by your code sample.

Assuming that your code is as you are showing in your example then as Bakuriu has pointed out the quotes around the input file name will be missing and ffmpeg will not handle the embedded space in the file name correctly. I also note that the path to the input file is not shown in your code which will be a problem your python application isn't running out of that directory.

Try amending the code as follows:

```
args1 = ["ffmpeg", "-i", '"my niece.mkv"']
```

Note the single quotes added to ensure that the file name gets wrapped in double quotes.